# What type of PCIe slot can the new PCIe SSD drives work with?

Tags: ssd, pci-express

I was looking at getting a computer into which I will insert an [Intel PCIe 400GB SSD drive (Intel 750 Series SSDPEDMW400G4R5)](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/solid-state-drives-750-series.html). I noticed that the [Lenovo P300 workstation](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/workstations/thinkstation/p-series/p300-tower/#tab-tech_specs) comes with several slots:

- 1 x PCIe x16
- 1 x PCI x4 (x16 Mechanical)
- 1 x PCIe x1
- 1 x PCI

Intel PCIe 400GB SSD drive seems to use a PCIe Gen3 x4 PCI connection.  Can I use any—or all—of these for the SSD drive?

Comment: While you're thinking about doing this, do be aware that Windows 8.1 is the first MS OS to natively support this kind of technology (NVM Express). Of course Win 10 is no problem. I have no idea about Linux support.

Answer (score 1):

[This SSD using PCIe x4 3.0](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/solid-state-drives-750-series.html).
Based on the specifications on [Lenovo Thinkstation website](http://thinkstation-specs.com/p300/), Lenovo P300 motherboard supports PCIe 3.0, and have PCIe x4 line, so you can use it for this SSD.

Of course, you can use both PCIe x4 line (16 physical) and x16 line slots for SSD drives, together or separately. But, according to specification, your workstation has the PCIe x16 graphic card onboard. So, without of removing the graphic card, you can plug to your workstation only one PCIe SSD disk.